# Wave Analytics, Analytics cloud and Einstien Analytics different

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

How is wave Analytics, Analytics cloud and Einstien Analytics different?
Is there a major difference or a detailed documentation where I can know about all these?
There is not much on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all comes down to the same thing.

[Salesforce Einstein Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.12) or Einstein Analytics (Wave) is the name of the technology powered by AI. Analytics cloud simply refers to the platform for connecting data from multiple sources and creating interactive views of that data, which is powered by Einstein, or again, Wave or Einstein analytics.